# Strange Characters at end of URL and 301 wont redirect them to correct url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

The below weird URLs popped up on Google console...

I didnt add them and I dont know where they came from.

- `https://www.example.com/gallery.html?page=3`
- `https://www.example.com/gallery.html?page=2`
- `https://www.example.com/gallery.html?page=1`

My 301 redirects in `.htaccess` are working for other pages but not these above URLs

Can anyone help me, I want to redirect them to `/gallery.html`

Added to my `.htaccess` which works for other redirects

```
RedirectMatch 301 /gallery.html?page=1 /gallery.html
```

Comment: What are the "strange characters"? Are you referring to the query string (ie. `?page=<number>`)? Although that looks like a "normal" query string for a _paginated_ "gallery"? So they don't look like "weird URLs" at all!? I'm wondering whether you should really be setting a `rel="canonical"` element instead (if you haven't already)?

Comment: The strange characters are ?page=3

Comment: I did setup the canonical but google  is still giving error "Alternative page with proper canonical tag"

Comment: Can you please tell me how to simply redirect those pages. The software that made those pages is gone and its not needed. I just want the Gallery.html page operating

Answer (score 0):

> The software that made those pages is gone and its not needed. I just want the `Gallery.html` page operating

(I assume you mean `gallery.html`, as per your examples?)

You can't match the query string part of the URL (everything after the first `?`) using a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` (or `Redirect`) directive. The `RedirectMatch` directive matches against the URL-path only. However, this also takes a regex, so `.` and `?` are special  characters in the regex.

You need to use mod_rewrite instead with an additional condition that checks the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

To redirect `/gallery.html?page=<number>` (where `<number>` is any sequence of digits 0-9) then you would need to do something like the following near the top of the `.htaccess` file (the order of directives is important):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to remove "?page=" query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=\d*$
RewriteRule ^gallery\.html$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. "`gallery.html`").

The `\d*` subpattern matches digits 0-9 zero or more times.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag is necessary to remove the query string from the redirected response.

If there are any other URL parameters in the query string then the redirect will not occur (since the regex won't match).

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

*Aside:*

> The below weird URLs popped up on Google console...
> I did setup the canonical but google is still giving error "Alternative page with proper canonical tag"

I'm not sure exactly where you are seeing that? But that doesn't necessarily look like an "error". (Your `rel="canonical"` tag appears to be correctly configured.)

A Google `site:` search on your domain does not return the URLs in question, only `/gallery.html`, so this redirect is probably not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all this. Its really appreciated.

Comment: So I added the code to the .htaccess as the first entrey but the site would no longer load with a 500 error unfortunatly.

Comment: "Error occurred: 500 - internal server error"

Comment: Regards your question about where im seeing it on Google console. its listed as a failed item for why the page isnt indexed.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what could be causing the 500 error?

Comment: @David What version of Apache are you using? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Is the code you are using exactly as written in my answer? What URL are you requesting? Does any URL result in this 500 error? The server's error log will contain the details of this 500 error. Either, you are using Apache 2.2 (not Apache 2.4) - in which case the `QSD` flag is invalid OR mod_rewrite is not installed on the server OR there is a conflict with other directives OR you've made a typo?!